# Facebook Connect for Flask

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, flask, facebook-oauth

With [Flask-OpenID](http://packages.python.org/Flask-OpenID/) there's a really nice OpenID module for the [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) framework.
However, facebook only supports FBconnect and no real OpenID.

I'm looking for a modified version of Flask-OpenID (if one exists) which supports FBconnect or a library doing FBconnect authentication in a similar way as Flask-OpenID.

Comment: Can't even flag this one.  A diamond mod asking an off-topic question: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.`

Comment: Heh, I wasn't a mod yet when asking it! Anyway, feel free to CV it - I don't think there's much need for further answers.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The [Flask-OAuth](http://packages.python.org/Flask-OAuth/) extension supports Facebook authentication:

```
facebook = oauth.remote_app('facebook',
    base_url='https://graph.facebook.com/',
    request_token_url=None,
    access_token_url='/oauth/access_token',
    authorize_url='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth',
    consumer_key=FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    consumer_secret=FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    request_token_params={'scope': 'email'}
)
```

Here's a full Facebook example: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-oauth/blob/master/example/facebook.py

Comment: The original Flask-OAuth suffers from lack of maintenance, and oauthlib is a promising replacement for python-oauth2. Flask-OAuthlib is designed to be a replacement for Flask-OAuth. It depends on oauthlib.

Answer (score 6):

You might also want to checkout Flask-Social as well (which is an extension on top of Flask-Security).  I'm in the middle of setting it up myself, but so far no issues.  Flask-Security, if you're not familiar, combines Flask-Login, Flask-Principal, and a few other extensions for a quick security layer, and Flask-Social adds the OAuth features.

Comment: So for an app where I want users to be able to login via Facebook or Twitter, & then set different roles etc, these two extensions (and their dependencies) are still (two years later) the go-to out-of-the-box solutions? They don't seem to be covered in the recent Flask Web Development book by @miguelgrinberg (but I have the early release).